# A set $C$ that is not closed in the weak* topology

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-topology

I have a problem, but first I would like to understand your statement. The statement is about a subset $C\subset l^{\infty}$ that is convex and closed in $C(l^{\infty}, |.|_{sup})$. I know that if $C$ is convex, then $C$ is closed in the weak topology.  So far, so good. The problem now asks to show that C is not closed in the weak* topology.

So, how can I say that $C\subset l^{\infty}$ is closed in weak* topology  if this topology is defined in its dual $l^{\infty '}$?

With this well-known, I would like a tip to show that 
$$C = \{x =(x_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \in l^{\infty} : 0\leq x_i \leq 1, x_i \to 1 \}$$
 is not closed in the topology weak*.

Comment: It is implicitly assumed that the weak* topology on $l^\infty$ means that we view it as the dual space of $l^1$.

Comment: _"So, how can I say that C⊂l∞ is closed in weak* topology **if this topology is defined in its dual $(\ell^\infty)^*$**?"_ Here they are considering the weak* topology of $\ell^\infty$ as the dual of $\ell^1$.

Comment: Can you find an element not in $C$ and a sequence in $C$ converging to it?

Comment: Hint: try to find a sequence converging to $0$, which is not in $C$

Comment: It was not clear yet, the convergence sequence has to be in $C$?

Comment: I think you're trying to argue that $C$ is not closed because there is a sequence in $C$ so that its point of convergence is not in $C$. But this is false because $C$ is closed in the norm of sup. Therefore, any sequence convergent in $C$ will be so that its limit is in C.

Comment: Okay, you're right. $(x^n)$ such that  $x^n = 1$ for $i> n$ and zero in other wise.  There is, in this case, weak * convergence to $0$. But $0$ is not in $C$.